# ASP.NET UpdatePanel + Wizard Problem

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm having troubles on an ASPX form using two ASP default components; The default components are the UpdatePanel (The one that is having troubles I believe) and the Wizard that works fine in many browsers.

The form with both components works fine on Firefox but crushes at the second step of the wizard.

Is there a documented bug about mixing these two components??

Any ideas??

Comment: crash? do you get an exception? which one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already solved it by myself.

Note for all of you:

When you use the ADO.NET Wizard component you can't put the Wizard inside an UpdatePanel, but each "step" of the Wizard inside an UpdatePanel, so the solution was to place three (3) UpdatePanel's  inside one Wizard component.